# ViewPager is Too Slow While is Swiping

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I am trying to do my own slider on Android with Java.
Before the asking this question, I made research so much but I could not find any solution.

My ViewPager is too slow when it's swiping on API 21, but it's great on API 23 or above.

these but I could not succeeded:

1. I have tried the *viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);*
2. I have tried to resize images.
3. I have tried to use Glide but later turned back to *setImageResource*.

   - 3.1 I have tried *DiskCacheStrategy.ALL*
4. I have tried to use RecyclerView instead of ViewPager but the same scrolling stuck.

   - 4.1 I have tried *recyclerView.setHasFixedFixedSize(true);*
   - 4.2 I did not do any process in *onBindViewHolder*
5. Even I did not put any image to ImageView still kept going.
   You can see my code below.

Activity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_timeline);

        //Slider Process
        ViewPager slider = findViewById(R.id.vpSlider);
        ViewPagerIndicator pagerIndicator = findViewById(R.id.vpiTimeline);
        SliderAdapter sliderAdapter = new SliderAdapter(slider.getContext(),listSliderUrl());
        slider.setAdapter(sliderAdapter);
        slider.setOffscreenPageLimit(10);
        pagerIndicator.setupWithViewPager(slider);
```

ViewPager Adapter:

```
public class SliderAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<Integer> urls;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public SliderAdapter(Context context, List<Integer> urls) {
    this.context = context;
    this.urls = urls;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return urls.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
    return (View)object == view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
    inflater = 

(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_slider,container,false);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_slider,container,false);
        ImageView iv = view.findViewById(R.id.ivSlider);
//        GlideApp.with(context).load(urls.get(position)).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).into(iv);
        iv.setImageResource(urls.get(position));
        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Recycler View Adapter:

```
public class RecyclerViewSliderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
```

```
Context context;
List<Integer> urls;

public RecyclerViewSliderAdapter(Context context, List<Integer> urls) {
    this.context = context;
    this.urls = urls;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolderSlider onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_slider,parent,false);
    ViewHolderSlider viewHolderSlider = new ViewHolderSlider(layoutView);
    return viewHolderSlider;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderSlider holder, int position) {
    holder.bindData(urls.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return urls.size();
}
```

}

```
class ViewHolderSlider extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
```

`ImageView ivSlider;
public ViewHolderSlider(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    ivSlider = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivSlider);
}
public void bindData(final Integer url){
    ivSlider.setImageResource(url);
}}`

//Here is my item_slider.xml

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivSlider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:layout_margin="0dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivGradient"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="111dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/gradient"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ivSlider"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSliderHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_light"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:textColor="@color/yellow"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tvSliderTitle"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:text="@string/dunya" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSliderTitle"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ivSlider"
        android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="31dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="TÜRKİYE'YE KARŞI\nHİSLERİM DEĞİŞTİ" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>`

Comment: Is `ViewHolderSlider` in a separate class file? And what was the problem with Glide? May also help to see the layout file for `item_slider`

Comment: @Murat Sahin, may be it will help you : try to change number of pages that are off screen, i.e. total number of pages minus 1

Comment: @PPartisan I used both, for now it's in the same file different classes. Glide also slow, it did not work for making faster to load.

Comment: @RishavSingla Unfortunately dude, did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually memory leaking, I was using ViewPager inside of ConstraintLayout, I changed ConstraintLayout to LinearLayout and problem solved! If you have a trouble like this, just try to change the outer layout.